# MFC: Using ContextMenuManager to TrackPopupMenu causes CTreeView item to retain TVGN_DROPHILITE status from time to time

Tags: mfc, treeview, contextmenu

I have a weird issue with a CTreeView context menu.   I was just calling `pPopup->TrackPopupMenu()` as is active in the code below.  No problems, but doesn't automatically update status text and icons.   So searching the Internet I found there is a `ContextMenuManager` for this in the MFC Feature Pack (I'm now using the BCGControlBar Pro which is what the feature pack was based on).

I tried using the `ContextMenuManager` in the code below (change the #if 1 to 0) and while it works, I find that sometimes (many times) afterwards the selected tree item will not show the highlight, it just flashes and goes back to the item that was right clicked on like `TVGN_DROPHIILITE` is still on.  (I confirmed `TVGN_DROPHILITE` is what the right click uses to select the tree item via the debug print items on the `OnNMRClick()` function). Also if I enabled the `treeCtrl.SelectDropTarget(NULL)` it fixes the issue but I shouldn't have to do that?

I'd really like to use the `ContextMenuManager` but this issue is a show stopper.  Does anyone know what is going on?

```
void CMyTreeView::OnNMRClick(NMHDR *pNMHDR, LRESULT *pResult)
{
    CDebugPrint::DebugPrint(_T("NMRClick: In DropHighlightItem %p\n"), GetTreeCtrl().GetDropHilightItem());

    // Send WM_CONTEXTMENU to self
    SendMessage(WM_CONTEXTMENU, (WPARAM)m_hWnd, GetMessagePos());

    CDebugPrint::DebugPrint(_T("NMRClick: Out DropHighlightItem %p\n"), GetTreeCtrl().GetDropHilightItem());

    *pResult = 0;
}


void CMyTreeView::OnContextMenu(CWnd* pWnd, CPoint ptMousePos)
{
    HTREEITEM htItem;
    CTreeCtrl &treeCtrl=GetTreeCtrl();

    //
    // ...
    //
  
    // the popup is stored in a resource
    CMenu menu;
    menu.LoadMenu(IDR_TREE_CONTEXT_MENU);
    CMenu* pPopup = menu.GetSubMenu(0);

   #if 1
    UINT id=pPopup->TrackPopupMenu(TPM_LEFTALIGN|TPM_RETURNCMD, ptMousePos.x, ptMousePos.y, this);
   #else
    CBCGPContextMenuManager *manager = theApp.GetContextMenuManager();
    UINT id;
    if (manager) {
      id=manager->TrackPopupMenu(pPopup->GetSafeHmenu(), ptMousePos.x, ptMousePos.y, this);
      // treeCtrl.SelectDropTarget(NULL);  // fixes issue
    }
    else id=0;
   #endif
   
   //
   // ...
   //
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `TVGN_DROPHILITE` is a temporary selection, only valid for the duration of drag-and-drop operation. Why are you messing with that?

You should use `TVGN_CARET`, if anything.

However, the problem is that right-click doesn't select the clicked item. If you like that behavior (I do), select it yourself.

It is also strange that you `// Send WM_CONTEXTMENU to self` - the `WM_CONTEXTMENU` should be sent to you by the system, in response to right click.

Comment: It's set by something in the framework or common control because the NMRClick shows that something set it. It sets it even when it works, it's something within that contextmenumanager that is causing it to not be unset, if I force it unset, it always works (I can also drag/drop something which resets it within my code). Without trapping NMRClick you have to double-right-click the tree item for the context message to be sent.